# For SEO can a paragraph contain headings rather than using headings above paragraphs?

Tags: seo, heading

Instead of the usual form

```
<h1>header1</h1>
<h2>header2</h2>
<h3>header3</h3>
<p>paragraph containing header1 and header2 and header3</p>
```

would it it matter if i used this form instead?

```
<p>paragraph containing <h1>header1</h1> 
and <h2>header2</h2> and <h3>header3</h3></p>
```

Comment: I think it might be useful to know more about the structure of your web page. I haven't seen header tags used this way so my gut feeling is not to do it, but I can't rule out that it might make sense in broader context.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister i try to shorten my page by gutting the h1, h2, h3 tags and putting them in the paragraph because all headers will always be used in the paragraph so i thought to handle the repetition by removing the headings from above the paragraph and put tag up the headers inside of the paragraph

Answer (score 1):

Google doesn't care much about what tags you use these days.  Historically Google put extra weight on words in header tags because Googlebot only looked at the source code of the page and could pick those tags out.   Today Googlebot renders pages to see what words are prominent on the page.  I wouldn't try to include `h1`, `h2`, and `h3` tags just for SEO.   I'd use those tags because they structure the data on the page and make it easy to style your headings in ways that are appropriate for users.  Google will give extra weight to the text in the headings when they see they are rendered prominently for users.

Using header tags inside paragraphs isn't going to work well.   Those tags are block level elements and will cause different text sizes, line breaks and extra white space within your paragraphs.  If you use CSS to style the text in the headers so that it looks just like other paragraph text, you lose all the possible SEO benefits of using those tags. In addition, it might actually look spammy to search engines and open your site up to an over-optimization penalty for stuffing keywords.

In all likelyhood you can just remove headings from your site without hurting your SEO.   I wouldn't try to stuff headers inside paragraphs in an attempt to preserve rankings when doing so.